# What size LVL beam do I need for a 9 foot 7 inch span on a load bearing exterior wall?

Tags: beam, replacement

I'm looking to put a LVL beam on an exterior load bearing wall that the opening is 9 ft 7 in.

It's a single story home in Southeast Michigan, the roof is above with roof trusses resting on top wall plate every 24" on center. It has a storage in attic.

Comment: Should get a  structural engineer.  We don't even know the load it is bearing.  Single story or first floor in a ten story building or maybe a few hot tubs plus playmates.

Comment: Is this a one story or two story house?  What is the span of the joists that rest on this opening? Where are you located (is there heavy snow loads?)

Comment: What is the span of the roof trusses? (What is the width of your house?)

Comment: Lee Sam the width of the house is 25' 8" if you want I can take pictures currently it has a glued laminated beam that is 3 inches wide and 12 inches tall by 10 foot 2 inches long I would like to replace it with a LVL that is not as tall if possible.

Answer (score 0):

At 24" centers you would get away with an 2"x8" especially if it was an LVL beam. Technically even a pine beam which is the weakest of all the woods including douglas fir and hem fir would comply as at 24" center can support a 9'8" span. Personally I would always upgrade and go for a 2"x10"

Because LVL beams are manufactured most of the manufacturers put out their own span tables with live and dead loads. You could look at them for an idea.

Ultimately though if you are not sure I would consult a structural engineer. It is certainly not something to get wrong.

Comment: I was looking a two 1 3/4" by 7 3/4" by 10 foot long LVL.